# Material design: Change toolbar color when navigation drawer is opened

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, material-design

I'm trying to recreate the material design toolbar as seen in the google play store, where the navigation drawer doesn't overlap the toolbar itself, but does overlap it's tabs. My main activity looks like this with the closed drawer on the left and the open drawer on the right:

[image: Screenshots]

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/spotview_content_fragment"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

I didn't add any other code for the drawer yet. As you can see, the drawer doesn't overlap the toolbar, but does overlap the tabs, just like I wanted. However, the tabs get a darker shade of orange, while the toolbar doesn't. How can I get the toolbar to become a darker color too like it does in the play store? I think it would look better that way so the tabs and the toolbar look like they belong together. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the toolbar to become darker you will have to put it inside the `DrawerLayout` and move everything else inside it to stay bellow the toolbar. The `DrawerLayout` code will make the toolbar darker just like play store.

Also make sure your toolbar height is `@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/spotview_content_fragment"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0px"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I move the toolbar in the DrawerLayout, the drawer will overlap the toolbar as well, which is what I started out with and what I don't want. If I place the toolbar there, how can I make sure the drawer doesn't overlap it?

Comment: I'm building a xml for you. Will post it soon

Comment: @AndroidCoder85 Also make sure your toolbar has fixed height (`@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material` )

Comment: So if I understand correctly the margin_top in the listview let's the drawer start at x=abc_action_bar_default_height_material? That seems like it should work. I'll test it later today and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Yes you're correct. You're making the menu stay bellow the toolbar. That's why I remind you to set the height of the toolbar so you don't get different margins.

Comment: In that case I can also remove the outer LinearLayout and start with the DrawerLayout, since that would become all that is contained by the LinearLayout.

Comment: Yes I think you can. However let me tell you that the toolbar root view should not be the drawerlayout. That's why I wrapped it inside a relativelayout.

Comment: Great, that did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch!